# Help understanding definition of the ($\mu$-)null set.

Tags: measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, almost-everywhere

Let $\left(X,\mathscr{A},\mu\right)$ be a measure space. In René Schilling's *Measures, Integrals and Martingales*, Definition 11.1 reads:

> A $\left(\mu-\right)$*null set* $N\in\mathscr{N}_\mu$ is a measurable set $N\in\mathscr{A}$ satisfying
> $$
> N \in \mathscr{N}_{\mu} \Longleftrightarrow N \in \mathscr{A} \quad \text { and } \quad \mu(N)=0.
> $$

There are two things that confuses me about this definition:

- $\mathscr{N}_\mu$ has not been defined.
- In the first line of the definition we *picked* an $N$ that is in both $\mathscr{N}_\mu$ and $\mathscr{A}$, so what is the purpose of saying that it must satisfy $N \in \mathscr{N}_{\mu} \Longleftrightarrow N \in \mathscr{A}$?

Comment: I agree that the writing is unclear, but it appears that Schilling is defining $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ to be the collection of all $\mu$-null sets.

Comment: Ah.  As noted in the text on page 80, the set $\mathcal{N}_{\mu}$ is defined in exercise 4.10 on page 29.  (the page numbers are from the [Google preview of the book](https://www.google.com/books/edition/Measures_Integrals_and_Martingales/_OjSIphIrH0C?hl=en&gbpv=1).)

Comment: @XanderHenderson, the definition you refer to makes a lot more sense. Thank you.